# FCM не работает при входе в Doze mode на Android 6+

Tags: android, fcm

У меня есть Android приложение с **FCM** интеграцией, мы используем **data notifications** (сервер не отправляет поле "notification", только "data"). Пуши отлично работают, если приложение свернуто и закрыто, но после ухода в Doze mode, андроды 6 и 7 версии перестают отображать пуши, только если заного открыть приложение, не понимаю в чем причина.

**P.S. com.HIDDED.channel заменил я сам.**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
           <service
            android:name=".service.PlainPushService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
           </service>


            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="com.HIDDED.channel" />
```

PlainPushService.kt

```
class PlainPushService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        // CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, потому что его иначе закроют

Comment: Прошу прощения.

Comment: Какую версию FCM используете? Если обновляли, то раньше работало?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что долго, не заметил вопрос, версия 17.4.0, раньше использовал GSM